# Grails cannot import classes outside grails-app folder

Tags: grails

I've placed classes in src/groovy/../../test.groovy and imported it from controller.

For some reason, the grails app returns errors when I do run-app and says "cannot resolve the symbol." Anything that's within the grails-app folder seems to work fine.

I'm using grails 1.3.x

Can anyone tell me why this is happening? File permission doesn't seem to be the problem.

Comment: Classes added to `src/groovy` were not picked as continuous change unlike `grails-app` directory. Try `grails compile` and then `grails run-app`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

grails -classpath ... run-app should do the trick.  But, keep in mind there are several (conventional) locations to put source code...